# Getting "Not Found" error for the php app in spite of deploying it successfully in Opsworks. Other php apps are working fine

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, aws-opsworks

I am getting "Not Found" error for the php app in spite of deploying it successfully in Opsworks. Other php apps are working fine. Also, i am able to run the app in my local environment using Xampp.

Can anybody throw some light on this please ?

Comment: 404 = Page Not Found, Are you sure file was there ?

Comment: Yes, i have deployed the file on app layer successfully. I can see it in list of apps.

Comment: Oh, are the path you construct was right, Have you tried in direct url in browser ?

Comment: Yes, i am giving instance server ip/app.php to call the app and then it says url not found on this server

Comment: You can't able to see the file in direct url through browser itself ??

Comment: Are you including the `home/public_html..` like this  ?

Comment: That is correct Sulthan. I can't see in direct url itself. Something like 52.x.x.136/abcd.php

Comment: Oh,, Can you show you url (You shall hide the full path)

Comment: Okay, getting chat notifications.. :-)  what i typed earlier is pretty much the url..hiding appname and ip address there..

Comment: Now the problem is fixed ?

Comment: Nope !! same issue..

Comment: Ah, **Can you able to call the file from browser directly ?**

Answer (score 0):

Well..i was deploying it repeatedly on the same ec2 instance and getting the 404 error on accessing it. I started a fresh instance, deployed the app on it and it's working fine now. Thanks everybody who looked into this for me. Cheers !!